# Are dc and ac currents produce electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge

I have four different situation and i want to learn what kind of field (electric or magnetic) each produces and which produces electomagnetic waves?

1)dc current flow in a conductor

2)ac current flow in a conductor

3)q charge moving v velocity

4)q charge with a accelleration

Comment: What do you want to know about electromagnetic waves?

Answer (score 2):

1) DC-current will result in a constant magnetic field, the right hand rule can be used here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field#Magnetic_field_and_electric_currents for more information on that. An electromagnetic wave is not "produced" in the steady state case, as we ignore the activation operation.

2) An AC-current will result in a alternating magnetic field. An alternating magnetic field will cause an alternating electrical field and voila - you just made an antenna and will send electromagnetic waves. Anyhow, its a very bad antenna, but there are a lot of tricks to make them better.

3) Is the same case as 1)

4) An accelerated charge will always result in bremsstrahlung, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung for more information on that.

Comment: Afaik, For 3 the result is not quite the same as a dc current flowing in a conductor, because of the spatial and temporal dependence of the magnetic field.

The way to obtain the result is to Lorentz transform the Coulomb field into a frame where $q$ is moving with velocity $v$. I don't think $E$ vanishes in this case, unlike a conductor in which $E$ is zero.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right there. I overlooked the current is not continuous in this case.